# Can MS Word read OpenOffice formats?

Tags: microsoft-word, openoffice

I am using  Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS, but am required to produce a document readable by MS Word. Can MS Word read .odt documents, or is OpenOffice capable of **exporting** into a .doc format so that it is **seamlessly read by MS Word**?

I'm using the following version of OpenOffice:

```
Source: openoffice.org
Version: 1:3.2.0-7ubuntu4
```

My installation is an older one, maybe the newer version of the ooffice works better with exporting to .doc? I've noticed. for example, that when I export to doc and insert images into the file, if I read the .doc file again, the images are not there.. as well as some formatting glitches.

Is there a version of openoffice/libreoffice that is known to export to a format of MS Word in a way that doesn't introduce formatting errors?

Comment: How about to use a mediator? Try export to HTML (or any other common or "middle" format) and open it in Word. (This should be a comment, but I don't have enough rep. Sorry.)

Comment: We need to know what version of Office exactly your asking about.

Comment: You say that you are required to write it using MS word and then say that you are using OOO. Do you actually mean that is has to be readable in MS word? Also, new versions of MS office are able to read ODS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open office can export to docx and doc. its in the save as dialogue box.

[http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Getting_Started/File_formats](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Getting_Started/File_formats%20Open%20office%20File%20formats)

Comment: The OP indicates that they had tried that. _"I've noticed. for example, that when I export to doc and insert images into the file, if I read the .doc file again, the images are not there.. as well as some formatting glitches."_

Comment: @Steve I know this, but when I re-read the document which has been exported, the images are missing.

Comment: I have noticed on occasions that when you open a odf saved as a doc(x) inside open office, the formatting goes a bit wafty, but it opens fine on a windows machine with word. Might be worth trying

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can ever be sure of a perfect translation, but not only will OO export as doc(x) as Steve suggest, but Office (2010) can read odt files. You mention ods, which are spreadsheets - I assume this is a typo?

Basic features should work well, if not render identically to the originals. If you are having problems with images, you may find different ways of embedding images in the source document.

In case I've not been clear, do not expect a perfect job; exporting to competing formats is low on any product's priority list, and besides, there is every incentive to not to do a 100% job!

Comment: it was a typo, I fixed it.. What you're saying makes complete sanse. :) I'll try to view the exported document and see how much it changes.